# Connecting to MongoDB Droplet from Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have a Kubernetes Cluster with some deployments and a LoadBalancer service running on DigitalOcean that I need to connect to a MongoDB that is in a droplet running **outside** the cluster, but also on DigitalOcean.

I have allowed on the MongoDB machine connections to the 27017 port from the External IP generated by the LoadBalancer service, it seems, however, that the connections requests from Kubernetes to mongo are not made using this IP, causing the following warning when deploying my application (which makes the Pods to restart eternally).

```
ConnectionError: Mongodb connection failed after 1 attempts with message: connection timed out
    at /usr/app/node_modules/@nindoo/mongodb-data-layer/dist/connections/mongodb.js:38:23
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/usr/app/node_modules/@nindoo/mongodb-data-layer/dist/connections/mongodb.js:6:65)
```

The connection works just fine when I'm running my application locally (since I add my local machine public IP to the firewall settings on the MongoDB droplet). I don't want to allow requests from *"Anywhere"* for security reasons.

It is possible to do what I want or should I deploy mongo in the Kubernetes Cluster?

I'm using Kubernetes v1.18.3

**EDIT:**

I'm connecting to mongo using the [@nindoo/mongodb-data-layer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nindoo/mongodb-data-layer) npm package. It's a package created by my company team which implements a `createConnection` function that takes as parameter a config object:

```
import { createConnection } from '@nindoo/mongodb-data-layer'

const config = { 
  database: {
    mongodb: {
      uri: env.get('DATABASE_MONGODB_URI', 'mongodb://<droplet_ip>:27017/'),
      dbName: env.get('DATABASE_MONGODB_DBNAME', '<database_name>'),
      maximumConnectionAttempts: 1,
      options: {
        authSource: '<authenticationDatabase>',
        auth: {
          user: '<admin_user>',
          password: '<admin_password>',
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const mongodbConnection = await createConnection(config.database.mongodb)
```

Comment: please share how are you trying to connect to mongo from your application.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Tarun. I just provided more information about how I'm trying to connect to mongo from my application.

Comment: are you on cloud or on prem ? Additionally can you go inside you application pod and `curl -s checkip.dyndns.org` and tell the output. This will show the Egree IP of your service.

Comment: I'm on cloud, more specifically on DigitalOcean. I ran the ```curl -s checkip.dyndns.org``` command and obtained an IP address, which I noticed is different from the LoadBalancer generated IP that I allowed traffic from on my mongo droplet.

Comment: Try allowing that IP in your firewall , jst to be sure your k8s is on digitalocean as well, right ?

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much, Tarun! I had to first allow traffic from anywhere on my mongo droplet, as my pods keeped restarting because of the connection error. Then I could exec inside the pod, get its IP and add it to to the mongo droplet firewall.

Comment: And yes! My k8s is on digitalocean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Egress IP of the k8s application is not same as your LoadBalancer IP. To confirm go inside the pod and run `curl -s checkip.dyndns.org` . This will give your Egress IP . You can allow this in your firewall and work.

Ideal way is to have Egress IP fixed and Digital Ocean doesn't support as per the blog [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/is-it-possible-to-have-a-static-outgoing-ip-in-kubernetes). You can follow up with Digital Ocean for same.

You can also use a Cloud NAT to fix the Egress IP depending on your needs.